# Not able to connect to Mongodb vie mongo shell

Tags: ssl, mongodb

I am no able to connect to mongodb via mongo shell.

command:

```sh
sudo mongo --tls --tlsCertificateKeyFile server.pem --tlsCAFile CA_INTERMEDIATE --host "mongodb://xxx:xxx@some-url:27020/data_base?ssl=true"
```

error:

```
MongoDB shell version v4.4.3
connecting to: mongodb://some-url:27020/data_base?compressors=disabled&gssapiServiceName=mongodb&ssl=true
{"t":{"$date":"2021-01-08T14:55:17.158Z"},"s":"E",  "c":"NETWORK",  "id":23256,   "ctx":"js","msg":"SSL peer certificate validation failed","attr":{"error":"SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to verify the first certificate"}}
Error: couldn't connect to server some-url:27020, connection attempt failed: SSLHandshakeFailed: SSL peer certificate validation failed: unable to verify the first certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:374:17
@(connect):2:6
exception: connect failed
exiting with code 1
```

However, this works when I am using the same keys, certificate and parameters with mongoDB Compas.

[image]

can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?